# Xamarin building_problem after update to IOS 11

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have updated my system to IOS 11. Visualstidio for Windows with all newest xamarin updates, Mac os Sierra is up to date and Xcode is the newest Version.

My Problem:
If I want to debugging on the simulator, the following error occurs:

```
Error error HE0046: Failed to install the app 'ch.ABC' on the device 'iOS 11.0 (15A372) - iPhone 6 Plus': lstat of /Users/administrator/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/ABC/a3481f272dab3f68e6e828203695f442/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/ABC.app failed: No such file or directory
```

The ABC.app exist in this path on Mac.

Buildlog:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The file '/Users/administrator/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/ABC/a3481f272dab3f68e6e828203695f442/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/build-signature/signature' was not found on the Mac
File name: '/Users/administrator/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/ABC/a3481f272dab3f68e6e828203695f442/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/build-signature/signature'
at Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.MessagingFileManager.d__11.MoveNext() in C:\d\lanes\5126\bd7e3753\source\xamarinvs\src\Messaging\Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh\MessagingFileManager.cs:line 171
```

this signaturefile is also on the right path.

**My attempts to fix the error:**

-Clean & rebuild has no effect.

-Delete the bin and obj Folder has no effect.

-I made the provisioning completely new has no effect.

-New projects work.

-This project work wehn i build it in Visual studio for mac

Has anyone an idea what could be the problem here?

thanks
Andreas

**Edit:
I think that it is a general Xamarin problem. Old projects (before IOS11) can not run after update to IOS 11 in the simulator.**

Comment: Exact same problem here. Following this thread with great interest.

Comment: Vstudio for Mac was giving me same issue.  My temporary "fix" for this issue was to go to XCode, Preferences, Components, and download the 10.3.1 simulator.

To be clear, a brand new wizard-generated project launches fine with iOS 11 simulator. I spent a long while comparing what might be different in my "real" project in the csproj and other project-related files. I tried changing several of the differences but couldn't change the broken behavior. I'm going to assume Xamarin will find/fix this issue at some point and stick with the 10.3.1 simulator for now.

Answer (score 5):

So, I decided to do the whole exercise of step by step mutating a newly created project (which deploys fine to the iOS 11 simulator) into my project (which does not) by using Beyond Compare to change file by file until no difference remains.

That took a good four hours (big project). All of that was to no avail however. :)

Because it turns out that what made the difference in the end was **removing the iOS project from the solution and then adding it back** (using the "add existing project" command).

This changes three things in the solution file:

1. Updates it to the latest VS solution format version.
2. Moves the iOS project to the bottom in a few places.
3. Fixes up some weird build configuration and/or platform configuration inconsistencies.

Naturally, I thought the last one would be the trick, so I tried only applying that delta in isolation, but that actually didn't fix the issue! I don't fully understand why, but actually performing the action of removing and re-adding the project does.

Very curious to see whether this works for others.

Comment: Tried a lot of different solutions, this worked. Thanks @Daniel-rosenberg. I just tried to open a 2016 solution to fix and never saw an issue like this before